# How is "誰も" used in this sentence?

Tags: translation, particles, meaning

I am a bit confused about a sentence I came across in an anki deck:

誰もその話を知らない。

I know that that 誰 means "who" and も means "also", but the translation it gives me is:

"No one knows that story."

Someone please explain.

Thank you n_n

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`誰` by itself does not mean 'who'. Nor does `も` always mean 'also'. Words like `誰` are called indeterminates, and are more essential than wh-words (It can be a part of the meaning of a wh-word; Not wh-word itself). `誰` only means 'some variable (something that does not have a fixed reference) that ranges over people'. Depending on what particle it is used with, it would be translated into different words in English:

> 誰 who
>   誰か someone
>   誰も anyone/everyone

Comment: Thank you so much! I haven't learned about indeterminates yet. You were very helpful. It makes a lot of sense now. n_n

Answer (score 3):

used with a negative verb 誰も means no one or nobody.

誰もその卑わいな冗談を笑わなかった。No one laughed at the obscene joke.

Used with a regular verb (positive?) it can mean anyone, anybody, everybody or everyone.

誰もがその話を知っている。Everyone knows that story.

誰もそのことに異存［異論］はない。Everyone agrees about that.　（No one objects to that.)

here are a number of examples
http://eow.alc.co.jp/誰もその/UTF-8/?ref=sa

Comment: [誰もその話を知っている。Everyone knows that story.] - Shouldn't that be `誰でも` or `誰もが`?

Comment: I also was going to ask about 誰でも. So does it mean everyone or anyone? Or something else entirely?

Comment: @dotnetNOOb it can mean everyone , anyone or noone when used with ない. depends on context:
  http://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=誰でも&ref=sa